# Renomear objetos, propriedades e métodos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Como é que eu posso renomear objetos, propriedades e métodos para os nomes que eu quiser, substituindo assim os antigos que deixariam de existir. Por exemplo, eu tentei o seguinte código:

```js
documento = document;
documento.corpo = documento.body;
documento.corpo.estilo = documento.body.style;
documento.corpo.estilo.fundo = documento.body.style.background;

delete document;

document.body.style.background = "#141414";  // funciona mas não devia
documento.body.style.background = "#141414"; // funciona mas não devia
documento.corpo.estilo.fundo = "#141414";    // não funciona mas devia
```

Um dos seus usos seria para mudar a língua do JavaScript mas também há outras possibilidades.

**Editado:**

Eu descobri como fazer para mudar o nome da propriedade, mas ainda não sei se é possível eliminar a original. Se calhar não se pode por ser algo essencial, apesar de eu ter feito uma cópia idêntica.

```js
documento = document;
documento.corpo = documento.body;
documento.corpo.estilo = documento.corpo.style;

// aparentemente delete não está a fazer nada
delete document;
delete document.body;
delete document.body.style;
delete document.corpo.style;

documento.corpo.style.background = "#141414";  // funciona
documento.corpo.style.background = "#141414";  // funciona
documento.corpo.estilo.background = "#141414"; // funciona
```

Comment: Simplesmente não faça isso. Provável que você não consiga usar nenhuma lib externa no seu projeto caso faça isso.

Comment: @Giovane, eu entendo o que tu queres dizer mas eu estou curioso se dá ou não para fazer e como. Eu também nunca uso nada externo por isso não haveria nenhum problema nessa parte.

Comment: Você até pode fazer uma cópia desse tipo de objeto, porém não é o que o seu código está fazendo (está fazendo uma referência, não cópia). Agora, apagar objetos como `window` e `document` provavelmente nem é possível, e se fosse causaria problemas sérios ao browser.

Comment: Realmente, apagar `document` ou `window` é impossível porque ambos possuem o atributo de propriedade `[[Configurable]]` definido como `false`. Desse modo, apagá-los se torna impossível (tanto é que, no modo estrito, utilizar `delete` ali causaria o lançamento de um erro). Relacionada: [O que são e como funcionam os descritores e atributos de propriedade do JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296)

Comment: No entanto, você poderia utilizar o objeto `Proxy` para criar um novo objeto `document`, novo `document.style` e afins, mapeando-os para o comportamento dos originais. No entanto, realmente não sei qual seria a motivação para isso. O trabalho seria enorme para algo realmente desnecessário... :/

Answer (score 2):

Não funciona porque porque `background` é apenas uma propriedade de `style`, que nessa cadeia de hierarquia é o último objeto que pode ser referenciado. Não vejo nenhuma produtividade ou aplicação prática para essa substituição, mas para fins de entendimento a discussão pode ter alguma validade.

Quando você faz isso:

```
let documento = document;
documento.corpo = documento.body;
documento.corpo.estilo = documento.body.style;
documento.corpo.estilo.fundo = documento.body.style.background;
```

Está apenas atribuindo o `value` de `background` à `fundo`. Apesar `estilo` ser uma referência de `style`, `fundo` é apenas um atributo adicionado por você e que o browser não está olhando para definir a cor de fundo, pois ele continua olhando para `background`.

Mais uma vez, não faz sentido nenhum você querer renomear objetos e propriedades do `DOM`, até porque o que está fazendo é apenas "clonar".