# O que são e como funcionam os descritores e atributos de propriedade do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, propriedade

Eventualmente leio, principalmente em conteúdos mais avançados sobre *objetos* em JavaScript, os termos "**descritores de propiredade**" e "**atributos de propriedade**". Creio que são conceitos relacionados.

- O que são eles e quais são?
- Qual o comportamento de cada atributo de propriedade?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Descritor de propriedade

Sabe-se que o JavaScript é uma linguagem que faz [uso extensivo de objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Para fazer com que alguns dos recursos da linguagem funcionem, é necessário associar algumas informações a cada uma das propriedades dos objetos. Isso é um exemplo de [metadado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/281398/69296).

Nesse sentido, um **descritor de propriedade** (em inglês *property descriptor*) é um tipo de meta-objeto que está associada a toda propriedade de qualquer objeto do JavaScript. Ele contém informações relevantes sobre como o *runtime* da linguagem tratará a propriedade ao qual pertence.

Dado o seguinte objeto:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
```

Cada descritor de propriedade corresponde a uma determinada propriedade de um objeto. Desse modo, no exemplo acima, todas as propriedades de `obj1` – como `a`, `b` e aquelas herdadas pelo protótipo – possuem um descritor de propriedade associado.

Os descritores de propriedade contém os **atributos da propriedade** (*property attributes*), que controlam a propriedade a qual o descritor de propriedade se refere.

## Atributos de propriedade

Cada propriedade de um objeto possui atributos (os chamados atributos de propriedade – ou *property attribute*). Eles controlam como a propriedade irá funcionar. São autênticos metadados das propriedades.

Por convenção, atributos de propriedades são referidos com uma notação utilizando dois colchetes. Por exemplo, `[[Enumerable]]`.

Existem seis atributos de propriedades, mas eles se agrupam de acordo com a função da propriedade do objeto.

- Atributos específicos de *propriedades de dados*:

  - `[[Value]]`, que contém o valor da propriedade. Seu valor padrão é `undefined`.
  - `[[Writable]]`, um booleano que define se o valor da propriedade (`[[Value]]`) pode ser alterado. Seu valor padrão é `false`.
- Atributos específicos de *propriedades assessoras* (`getters` ou `setters`):

  - `[[Get]]`, que contém a função `getter`, invocada quando a propriedade é lida. Seu valor padrão é `undefined`.
  - `[[Set]]`, que contém a função `setter`, invocada quando a propriedade é definida ou redefinida. Seu valor padrão é `undefined`.
- Atributos gerais (tanto de *propriedades de dados* quanto de *propriedades assessoras*):

  - `[[Enumerable]]`, um booleano que determina se a propriedade é enumerável. Seu valor padrão é `false`.
  - `[[Configurable]]`, um booleano que determina se a propriedade é configurável. Seu valor padrão é `false`.

Existem diversos métodos que te permitem criar ou manipular propriedades com seus atributos modificados. Alguns deles são:

- [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), que cria um novo objeto. Você pode passar, no segundo argumento, um objeto contendo todas as propriedades iniciais com seus respectivos descritores de propriedade. Dentro de cada descritor, como dito acima, vão os atributos.
- [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), que define ou altera uma propriedade e seu respectivo descritor.

Por exemplo, abaixo vamos criar um novo objeto cuja propriedade `name` seja enumerável, e `lastName` seja não enumerável:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null, {
  name: {
    value: 'Luiz',
    enumerable: true,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  },
  lastName: {
    value: 'Felipe',
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  },
});

const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj);

console.log(descriptors);
```

Abaixo contém uma breve explicação e detalhamento sobre cada um dos atributos de propriedades, bem como algumas observações.

### [Atributos específicos de *propriedades de dados*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#table-2)

#### `[[Value]]`

O atributo de propriedade `[[Value]]` contém o valor da propriedade de dados. Não determina comportamentos além do próprio valor.

#### `[[Writable]]`

O atributo de propriedade `[[Writable]]` é um boleano que determina se a propriedade pode ser alterada através do operador de atribuição (`=`).

No [modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2746/69296) da linguagem, qualquer tentativa de alterar um valor cujo atributo `[[Writable]]` estiver como `false` lançará uma exceção. O método `Reflect.set` pode ser utilizado para tentar alterar uma propriedade sem lançar exceções, mesmo se `[[Writable]]` for `false`.

### [Atributos específicos de *propriedades assessoras*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#table-3)

#### `[[Get]]`

O atributo de propriedade `[[Get]]` determina uma função que será chamada, sem nenhum argumento, sempre que a propriedade for lida.

Por exemplo, assumindo que `name` seja uma propriedade assessora, seu atributo `[[Get]]` será invocado quando:

```js
// Irá invocar o atributo `[[Get]]` da propriedade `name` do objeto `obj`.
obj.name;
```

Quando a notação [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) é utilizada, uma propriedade assessora está sendo criado com o seu atributo `[[Get]]`.

#### `[[Set]]`

O atributo de propriedade `[[Set]]` determina uma função que será chamada, com um argumento, sempre que a propriedade for alterada.

Por exemplo, assumindo que `name` seja uma propriedade assessora, seu atributo `[[Set]]` será invocado quando:

```js
// Irá invcar o atributo `[[Set]]` da propriedade `name` do objeto `obj`.
// Passará a string 'Luiz' como primeiro (e único) argumento.
obj.name = 'Luiz';
```

Quando a notação [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) é utilizada, uma propriedade assessora está sendo criada com o seu atributo `[[Set]]`.

### Atributos gerais (tanto de *propriedades de dados* quanto de *propriedades assessoras*):

#### `[[Enumerable]]`

O atribto de propriedade `[[Enumerable]]` é um booleano que determina se a propriedade pode ser enumerada ou não.

O laço `for..in` e funções como `Object.keys` ou `JSON.stringify` só irão trabalhar com as propriedades cujo atributo `[[Enumerable]]` seja `true`. Propriedades não enumeráveis não serão listadas por esses meios.

No entanto, você pode utilizar métodos como `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` e `Reflect.ownKeys` para listar todas as propriedades do objeto – enumeráveis ou não. Veja:

```js
const obj = Object.create(null, {
  name: {
    value: 'Luiz',
    enumerable: true, // ⚠️
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  },
  lastName: {
    value: 'Felipe',
    enumerable: false, // ⚠️
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
  },
});

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj) // ['name']
);

console.log(
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj) // ['name', 'lastName']
);
```

#### `[[Configurable]]`

O atributo de propriedade `[[Configurable]]` é um booleano que determina se a propriedade pode ser configurada. Isso significa que, se uma propriedade tiver seu atributo `[[Configurable]]` definido como `false`, você não será capaz de:

- Deletar a propriedade do objeto (utilizando `delete` ou qualquer outro meio, como `Reflect.deleteProperty`);
- Alterar seu descritor de propriedade – atributos de propriedade não podem mais ser editados para aquela propriedade. Isso significa que você não será nem capaz de alterar `[[Configurable]]` de volta para `true`!

  - Você poderá, no entanto, no caso de propriedades de dados, alterar o atributo `[[Value]]`, caso `[[Writable]]` esteja definido como `true`.
  - Você poderá, também, alterar `[[Writable]]` para `false`, mas *não* o contrário.

Essa última exceção (de poder tornar `[[Writable]]` `false`) existe já que, no JavaScript, a propriedade `length` de arrays sempre teve o atributo `[[Configurable]]` definido como `false`, mas `[[Writable]]`, como `true`. Desse modo, para implementar o método `Object.freeze`, a especificação ECMAScript precisou estabelecer aquela última exceção para não quebrar código legado.

---

## Referência:

- [Especificação ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/);
- Capítulo 17 do Livro "*[Speaking JS](http://speakingjs.com/)*".